# send a page to a div within another page

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have a page, "index.php". I have defined an iframe within this page which contains "alphabets.php",  This iframe basically displays alphabets from "A" to "Z" and if you click on one of the alphabets I get a list of all articles which  begin with that particular alphabet. For example, if I click B, then I get a list of all articles which begin with "B". When I click on article name, I would like to display the article in an iframe which I have defined in a DIV on another page,  "details.php".

Can someone help me with this one?

Regards

Sachin

Answer (score 0):

```
    function loadArticle(url) {
    var sitelink = url+'?toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=0';
    document.getElementById('iFrameName').src = sitelink;
}

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="loadArticle('../URLtoDetails/details.php')">Alphabet</a>
```

Comment: Hi Jay, Thanks, I tried to use it but It gives an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: loadArticle is not defined"

Comment: DId you enclose the function definition within <script type="text/javascript"> tag ? Also ensure the function is defined, before the html. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried it and it is still not working. I have defined the javascript function loadArticle in "alphabets.php" . <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="loadArticle('../URLtoDetails/details.php')">Alphabet</a> is also defined in "alphabets.php". The "iFrameName" is in "details.php". I guess you too have done the same? If not, please let me know. In my case, document.getElementById('iFrameName').src is null :-(

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried the solution provided here [link] http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/85547-linking-iframe-another-page.html ..and it works as required. Thanks for all the help